# How do I switch between layouts (like the ICS+ calculator sort of) with slide?

Tags: java, android, layout, swipe, gesture

I currently use the onBackPressed() to switch between layouts in an android app, but that's not a very traditional method. I want to implement a swipe/slide gesture to switch between them. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `ViewPager` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Also have a look at official examples here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html